# Pyplot: Contour lines that enclose a certain number of points (or a certain probability value) in a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, kernel-density

I want to create a PDF from a scatter plot. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
data = np.column_stack((x, y))
nbins = 100
xmin = -0.5; xmax = 0.5; ymin = -5; ymax = 5
k = kde.gaussian_kde(data.T)
xi, yi = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:nbins*1j, ymin:ymax:nbins*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.5,4))
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), shading='gouraud', cmap='Purples')
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), levels = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1, 1.5], linewidths=1, linestyles='dashed', cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$]')
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--')
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=600)
plt.close(fig)
```

And this is the plot I'm getting from the code:

[image]

I have two questions about this:

- It seems there's a problem with the PDFs since I can draw contour lines at levels 1 and 1.5 and since it's a PDF, values should be below 1.
- How can I draw contour lines that enclose a certain number of points or at a certain probability level?

**Data**: [x](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kwedda2rm1p06zf/x.npy/file) and [y](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1u05ylkmqjbso32/y.npy/file). (Format: [npy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).)

Comment: PDFs are not limited by 1. The only requirement is that the *integral* equals 1. The second question is probably hard, it would involve to calculate the integral dynamically to interatively arrive at the required level that encloses the desired probability.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! What is the meaning then of the levels of the contour lines? What does it mean to have a contour line at 1.5, for example?

Comment: In this case the contour line at 1.5 show the region where the probability density is 1.5. It thereby encircles the region where the probability density is higher than 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
plt.savefig('Testing.pdf', format='pdf')
```